# Data not being changed in TextBox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

Ok, I have been going around and around with this for hours (Searching, etc). This is what I want to do, I want to load data into a Text Box and if the user changes the text in the Text Box I want to be able to save the new text.

My problem in the TxtBox_TextChanged event the data contained in the txtNarrative Text box is the new data that the user typed in (<>ABCD) but in the btnSubmit_Click event the data contained in txtNarrative is the original value ABCD.

What am I doing wrong??

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="WorkBench_VBNet._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <fieldset>
        <span class="title">Entry Form</span>
            <ul class="pageitem">
                <li class="Narrative">
                    <asp:TextBox EnableViewState=true ID="txtNarrative" placeholder="Narrative" Width="100%" 
                            Rows="10" TextMode="multiline" runat="server" Height = "100%" OnTextChanged="TxtBox_TextChanged" >
                    </asp:TextBox></li>

                <li class="Submit">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSubmit" runat="server">Submit</asp:LinkButton>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code Behind:

```
Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public Event TextChanged As EventHandler

    Protected Sub TxtBox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, _
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtNarrative.TextChanged


        ViewState("txtNarrative") = txtNarrative.Text ''<-- The text here is the changed text not ABCD
        txtNarrative.Text = ViewState("txtNarrative").ToString

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
        Dim Narrative as String = txtNarrative.Text '<-- the text in the text box is still ABCD not what was changed.

        ''Code to update data in the Database goes here
    End Sub


    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            txtNarrative.Text = "ABCD"
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Why you need this code  `ViewState("txtNarrative") = txtNarrative.Text 
        txtNarrative.Text = ViewState("txtNarrative").ToString`? why can't you just use  `txtNarrative.Text`

Comment: I did that to see if using the ViewState property would make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `TxtBox_TextChanged` Sub, it's not needed, the [`IPostBackDataHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackdatahandler.aspx) of the `TextBox` will do that for you:

```
<asp:TextBox EnableViewState=true ID="txtNarrative" placeholder="Narrative" Width="100%" 
                        Rows="10" TextMode="multiline" runat="server" Height = "100%"  >
                </asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question but:

You do not need to "OnTextChanged" textbox in your markup.

In your code behind you alredy have handles declaration.

If you use both ("OnTextChanged" on your html markup, and handles in your code behind) the text box event will trigger twice.

```
   Protected Sub TxtBox_TextChanged (ByVal sender As Object, _
         ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtNarrative.TextChanged


         ViewState ("txtNarrative") = txtNarrative.Text''<-- The text here text is not changed the ABCD
         txtNarrative.Text = ViewState ("txtNarrative"). ToString

     end Sub


  <asp: TextBox EnableViewState = true ID = "txtNarrative" placeholder = "Narrative" Width = "100%"
                             Rows = "10" TextMode = "multiline" runat = "server" Height = "100%">
                     </ asp: TextBox>
```

also tested your code and the value that is submitted is the new value in the textbox. (Ie if I understand your question)

Hope this helps